# Get attempts of exams for every course of every student

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL. I want to get attempts of exams for every course of every student.

I've made this query in my database:

```
SELECT students.id, students.surname, students.name, courses.name AS "course" FROM `students`
JOIN exam_student
ON exam_student.student_id = students.id
JOIN exams
ON exam_student.exam_id = exams.id
JOIN courses
ON exams.course_id = courses.id 
ORDER BY students.surname ASC, students.name ASC;
```

The query produces this
[image: result]

Now, what I want is to get for every user, the attempts of exams of every course name.

I have the exams pivot with user_id and course_id.

How can I reach this result?

Comment: Which result?..

Comment: without knowlegde of your database and data that produce your table it is basically impossible to guess, so produce a full [mre and read also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want a total.
So let's COUNT the attempts by aggregating it.

```
SELECT s.id, s.surname, s.name
, c.name AS course
, COUNT(e.id) AS exam_attempts
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN exam_student es ON es.student_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN exams e ON e.id = es.exam_id
LEFT JOIN courses c ON c.id = e.course_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.surname, s.name, c.id, c.name
ORDER BY s.surname, s.name, c.name;
```

Comment: Oww, Ok, it works! I've didn't expect that can Group by more than one column. Thanks!

Comment: MySql is probably one of the only RDBMS's that even allows not putting every selected field also in the group by ;)